# How to get a method I built to process a value of X

Tags: java

Step 1, ask the user for a value of x, then find the value of the function f(x) = 2x^3+3x^2+10. Solve for that value of x and print the result. Step 2, ask the user for another value for x, evaluate the function, and print the result. Do this implementing the following methods!!
-`public static double readDouble(String message)`
Displays a message to the user, reads a double and returns it. The message is passed to the method as an input parameter.
`public static double square(double x)`
Calculates the square of a number. Ex) x = 2, square(x) will return 4.
`public static double cube(double x)`
Calculates the cube of a number. Ex) x = 2, cube(x) will return 8.
`public static double evaluate(double x)`
Evaluates the function. Ex) x = 2, evaluate(x) will return 38.
`public static void displayResult(String message, double result)`
Displays a message to the user as well as the result.

Here is my code..something isn't right though. Does anyone see the issue?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticEquation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double x = null;
        String message = null;

        x = readDouble("Enter a value for x");

        System.out.println("f(x)=" + x);
    }

    public static double readDouble(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return input.nextDouble();
    }

    public static double square(double x) {
        return x * x;
    }

    public static double cube(double x) {
        return x * x * x;
    }

    public static double evaluate(double x) {
        return 2 * cube(x) + 3 * square(x) + 10;
    }

    public static void displayResult(String message, double result) {
        System.out.println("The result is:" + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. We're not here to hand out free answers to homework questions. 2. *"something isn't right though"* what isn't right exactly? Give us the error message or the intended behavior.

Comment: Please explain ["something isn't right though"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: Well when I try to get the code to "play", it only does anything for step one. All the other code I added isn't doing anything.

Comment: To make a method do something you have to call it and the only method that is called in you code is `readDouble()`.

Comment: "All the other code I added isn't doing anything" what code do you expect to do something? What makes you think it should do it? Hint: there is no magic here, methods do things only when they are invoked. Did you invoke all methods you wanted (in order you wanted)?

Comment: Okay.. So I want all the methods from "public static double readDouble(String message)" down to the bottom of the code to work together to solve for whatever the user gives for x. So right below "System.out.println("f(x)=" + x);"  I need to call for all of those methods...?

Comment: You don't need to call all methods from `main` one. One method can call another one, but your `main` method needs to call method which will be start of that *chain*. In your case it looks like you are not calling `evaluate` method from anywhere so it won't magically be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in your main method the line :

```
System.out.println("f(x)=" + x);
```

to

```
displayResult("f(x)=" , evaluate(x));
```

and in your displayResult method

```
System.out.println("The result is:" + message);
```

to

```
System.out.println("The result is: " + message + result);
```

Comment: Those two changes worked. It is now processing the methods I added in. Thank you all so much!